# Issue in storing cookies in the browers NEXTjs , Redux RTK query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm working on a project using Django for the backend. I'm getting the XCRF token through API cookies, as shown in the Postman image below.

[image]

I'm getting access through redux rtk query, also shown below:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const TestApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "TestApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["TestApi"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTestData: builder.query({
      query: () => "/user/csrf_cookie",
      providesTags: ["TestApi"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetTestDataQuery } = TestApi;
```

API Response:

[image]

Issues: there is not data in the cookies section.

Here is the cookies snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle cookies in your next.js project. I suggest you to go with this plugin js-cookie using this cookie library you can handle this issue.

Install this library like npm install js-cookie using in following ways

```js
import Cookies from "js-cookie";


Cookies.set("yourCookieName", "yourToken", { expires: 7 }); // Expires in 7 days
```